# 4 - 7 second delay accessing Mysql across the network

Tags: networking, mysql, slow-connection

our company has recently purchased a new server with the intention of replacing our aging database server.

its a full 64bit 2008 enterprise system, i have got the basic server setup and configured and then installed the 64bit version of mysql on the server, this has then been configured to match where possible our existing server as much as it can.

however i have noticed that when it was swapped with the production database server our software systems had an increased delay accessing the mysql database this was anything beween 4 - 7 seconds.

i have tried disabling TOE, IPv6 and a few other suggested soultions to this but so far cannot find out where this slowdown is coming from. replacing the server with the production one and the delay goes away.

in terms of software and hardware the servers are not very identical at all due to one being windows 2003 std with a 32bit server and the new one being windows 2008 enterprise with a 64bit server.

thanks
Kris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delays of circa 5 seconds always smell of DNS. Since that is the default timeout period of most resolvers.

As per the advice in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/15073), try testing the server with `skip_name_resolve` set and ensuring that the clients can correctly resolve the server's address if you're using hostnames. If the problem resolves itself (excuse the pun) then move onto ensuring that DNS is setup correctly in both directions.

Comment: this is exactly the issue i have added the option to skip name resolution into MYSQL (restarted service) and the delay disapeared..

so i now need to sort out my DNS problems and i should be happy again :)

thanks

Comment: @ Kristiann, DNS 'issues' like this are normally just cases of servers being given hostnames that don't resolve. So it's normally just a case of adding DNS records for the server.